# Why do different people have different levels of mitzvah obligation?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, mitzvah, taamei-mitzvot-reasons

If the point of giving us mitzvot is to allow us to earn a reward in olam haba and to perfect creation (there's all of Jewish philosophy boiled down into 102 characters), why wouldn't all Jewish adults be equally obligated in all mitzvot?

I understand someone who is physically unable to perform certain mitzvot but outside of that it would seem to be unfair to someone to exempt them. I realize that in some circumstances they can still perform the mitzvah even if they are not obligated to do so, but the rule is one who is obligated and performs is greater than one who is not obligated and performs.

So then why not simply obligate all who (can) perform equally?

Comment: Korach asked the same question... the answer is that there are different kinds of people.  Since HKB"H made the Torah and its laws and He also made "natural" laws, you might as well ask why not everybody is able to conceive children and give birth... in fact, more than half of all humans cannot do this!  Seems unfair, no?

Comment: @yoel The questioner specifically limited his 'request' to "obligat[ing] all who **(can)** perform equally" (emphasis mine), meaning accepting nature the way it is, why not obligate more people? He's not asking why men can't bring korbanei zavah; he's asking why I can't accept pidyon peter chamor.

Comment: @DoubleAA, but the fact that Hashem made different people different by physical nature also shows that they are different by spiritual nature.

Comment: @Yishai First of all, no it doesn't. Second of all, so what? I'm physically different from my brother, but we are both obligated in exactly the same mitzvot. So this hasn't really helped answer the question at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA, that only makes sense if you view the spiritual and physical as disconnected. But really one flows from the other. And of course people have different Mitzva observances at the individual level. Different communities, different hiddurim, "Ba Meh Haveh Zahir Tfei," Perek Echad Shacharis, vs. Toroso Umnoso, etc.

Comment: @Yishai Again I disagree. I can certainly imagine two different physical objects of the same spiritual nature, even assuming the two worlds are connected, because I don't pretend to know how that relationship manifests itself. For you second point, mitzva observances is different than mitzva obligations. My brother and I may have different ways of approaching life and Torah, but we're both obligated in the same number of the 613. So since we have different spiritual natures, why aren't we obligated in different amounts?

Comment: Must be that different spiritual natures is a logically insufficient indicator (if that) of different levels of obligation.

Comment: @Double AA, it is all about degrees of difference. Things can be slightly different, or they can be greatly different. Different isn't a binary state.

Comment: @Yishai Very true, but then your argument is irrelevant without describing which degrees are relevant. If two groups are physically different to extent X (which I'm not sure is always true: consider kohanim vs mamzerim), then how much should their difference in obligation be? I think you'll have a hard time describing those relationships.

Comment: @Double AA, the relevant distinction is that found in Torah, according to the obligations and observances proscribed in the Torah for different people. Anyway, the site is starting to yell at me for turning this into a discussion. But thanks for the back and forth. I'll let you have the last word.

Comment: You very well may be right that different levels of obligation derive from different spiritual backgrounds/natures, but [trying to prove it from the physical world](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17449/why-do-different-people-have-different-levels-of-mitzvah-obligation#comment39799_17449) will be challenging IMO.

Answer (score 3):

The result of having different people have different levels of mitzvah obligation, is that it requires all of Klal Yisroel to acheive all of the mitzvos. See [here by Rav Zechariah Tubi, Kerem B'Yavneh Rosh Kollel Rabbanut](http://www.kby.org/english/torat-yavneh/view.asp?id=3681) and an extract:

> All of Israel are responsible for one another, and through Klal
>   Yisrael's observance – all receive reward. The entire Israeli nation
>   is considered as one person, as it says: "You are My sheep, the sheep
>   of My pasture, you are Man." (Yechezkel 34:31) Just as a person has a
>   head, eyes, and a heart – so, too, in Klal Yisrael there are those who
>   are called, "the heads of the congregation," and others, "the eyes of
>   the congregation." The righteous are the heart of Israel. Each person
>   has to observe the mitzvot that is relevent to him, and in the
>   aggegrate – Am Yisrael is a whole person. However, an individual Jew
>   cannot fulfill all of the mitzvot of the Torah.

In (my) addition, we cannot know the **ultimate** point of giving us mitzvot and cannot judge what is fair from the viewpoint of HKB"H.

Comment: This implies that the righteous have different mitzvot then everyone else.

Comment: "However, an individual Jew cannot fulfill all of the mitzvot of the Torah." -- no one claimed everyone needs to be obligated in everything; just everything they can do. I'm personally capable of opening the doors in the mikdash, but I'm not allowed to since I'm not a Levi. Why not give me more opportunities?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think what he means is that since you're not a Levi and are therefore not responsible for opening the gates, you have more time on your hands to do other things which society needs. Basically by giving certain people and only them specific responsibilities, you not only insure that those things get taken care of, but you also give a certain freedom to the others - which automatically places the other responsibilities on them, which makes for a healthy society where everyone is involved. Letting everyone do as they feel might not achieve this goal. I think it's a great answer. +1

Comment: @DovF I think _that_ is a great answer, but I don't see it in this post. I encourage you to post that comment separately.

Comment: :) thanks, though I suppose I should wait until @AvrohomYitzchok clarifies whether or not this is what he meant.

Comment: @DovF I had not thought of the way in which in your comment explains what I posted. A new answer  incorporating your comment will be a marked improvement.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok done.

Answer (score 3):

To build upon [the answer given by Avrohom Yitzchok](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17478/1601): By giving specific people specific responsibilities, you not only insure that those things get taken care of, you also give a certain freedom to all the others - which automatically translates into various societal responsibilities being placed upon them, which makes for a healthy society where everyone is involved. Such a society can breed mutual respect in that each person recognizes that the other has a necessary role that I cannot fill - that I *need* the other. It also imbues special meaning in to a whole lot of actions which would have much less meaning otherwise. The Kohen feels special that he's the one delegated to perform the service, and the Israelite feels special that he is the one who has time and is therefore responsible for the upkeep of the land; and so on and so forth. Perhaps this is the reasoning behind the various levels of obligation for different people.